# Artificial Rainbows

Tags: visible-light, scattering, nature

We all know that rainbows are a consequence of scattering of light rays by the rain drops. But is it possible to create a artificial rainbow at a natural scale. I mean just the same as that caused by the natural phenomenon. And if it is possible, what should be required apparatus .

Comment: You mean something like this https://mybeautfulthings.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/rainbow-road-sign.jpg or like this http://epod.usra.edu/.a/6a0105371bb32c970b013485601e05970c-pi?

Comment: Nope.. I mean something on a natural scale

Comment: The answer is 42°

Comment: Or you mean something like this https://goo.gl/images/z4e1V2?

Comment: What is 'a natural scale'? Waterfalls seem pretty natural to me, and they do well, even man made ones.

Answer (score 2):

A garden hose (and a white light source) is all that's needed:

[image]

[Source](http://somethingsurprising.blogspot.de/2011/10/ever-thought-about-rainbows.html).

As for "natural scale", there really isn't one, since only the angle $\sim 42^\circ$ from the direction opposite to the light source is a constant. Thus, the "radius" $R$ of the rainbow you see is $R\approx L\sin{42^\circ}\approx 0.67L$, where $L$ is the observer's distance to the water droplets curtain that produces the rainbow.